# How to print entire scene contents in Actionscript 3 for Flash Builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, flash-builder

How do i print the entire scene contents to photographic paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the solution hours lately, behold a function that let's you print your scene contents in AS3, just by calling it:

```
private function printScreen():void

    {
        var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

        if ( !printJob.start() )
            return;

        printJob.addPage(Sprite(root));
        printJob.send()

        printJob = null;    

}
```

Just call it from a mouse/keyboard event and you're good to go.